# How is 40GB possible on Google Drive (not paid)(anymore)?

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

We've come to encounter a Google Drive account which was once paid since the data grew on it,
then the payments stopped, but the data still exceeded (around 22GB total) the quota of FREE tier which is 15GB.

Suddenly we've noticed that now there is no more warning about too much data, there was no payment (we checked pay.google.com activity for last payment) and the shown limit now seems to be 40GB, which is neither free tier, niether the 1st paid tier (which is 100GB).

Is there some Google Drive magic that does this?

Was the policy changed and maybe they added more storage for photos or something (photos here are over 20GB)? (I could not find anything like that)